# How to avoid a user receiving his own chat gcm notification on Pubnub

Tags: android, cordova, pubnub

We have created a chat application using pubnub api on phonegap. We are using a common unique channel for two users (say A & B) to send and receive messages. 
Also, in addition to this, we have enabled pubnub gcm notification so that users can receive notifications when their app is either in the background or closed. 
Now when a user A sends a pubnub message to B and instantly changes the application or hides it, then the user A himself also receives a gcm notification oh his own message. 
This is the only issue that is troubling us. Rest all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your subscribe callback, can you detect if the application is not in the foreground, and if not in the foreground, return immediately?

This way, the logic which would deliver received messages to your application logic simply doesnt fire unless you are in foreground... ?

Comment: Yes in the callback for the gcm notifications, we can detect if the app is in foreground or background. But it isn't going to help! Because this part of the code only runs when the app is opened when you tap on the notification received. I am talking about not receiving the notification at all. So essentially any code I write in the callback won't run when the application is in the background or closed. Please suggest something else.

Comment: Are you using the Presence feature?

Comment: Yeah we are using the presence feature for detecting 'is typing..' and online/ offline status and displaying that just like whatsapp does. If you are thinking of using presence to detect whether to send the gcm part or not, it won't work because the presence detection is not quick enough to detect the actual presence of users. Please tell.

Comment: Would you be able to increase the heartbeat on the client to reduce the Presence detection time?

Comment: I have submitted this as a feature request to filter out messages to self.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same similar problem you did and so I rigged something together that works for me.

```
private boolean isFromSelf(final Object msgSent){
    boolean isEcho = false;
    String msgText = msgSent.toString();
    JSONObject j;
    String receiver = currentUserId; //a unique string ID for each user
    try
    {
        j = new JSONObject(msgText);
        String senderID = j.get("senderID").toString();
        if (senderID.equals(receiver)){
            isEcho = true;
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return isEcho;
}
```

It makes the assumption that every user that publishes a message to a channel will send their unique Id as "senderID" included in the payload. Then when a message is received, extract it from the payload and check it against the user's Id. So I add isFromSelf method as the first thing that is called when I receive a message, like this:

```
pN = new Pubnub(pub_key, sub_key);
    try {
        pN.subscribe(CHANNEL_NAME, new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object msg) {

                if (!isFromSelf(msg)) {
                    //Now add here what you want to do with the message
                }
            }

            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "there was an error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So in your case, perhaps rig together a senderID check so that if you do receive a GCM from yourself, do not display notification at all, even if app is in background.